# Swf file does not run

Tags: flash

I have downloaded the build-a-meal swf file from [Nourish Interactive](http://www.nourishinteractive.com/kids/flash/games/build-a-meal/en/build-a-meal.swf).

I have uploaded SWF file to http://megaswf.com/s/2711334

But it is showing only the first layer.

Also I tried to open the swf file locally using adobe flash player,even then it is showing locally.

Any way to run the whole ActionScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Season W has mentioned in his answer, your swf file used many external files which you can see using the browser developer tools ( chrome in my case ):

[image]

With the same tool, we can see that there is some files (3 exactly: kitchen.swf, options.swf and select_menus.swf) which should be in a directory named *MakeMeal_Tutorial* which is in the same directory as your *build-a-meal.swf* and xml files, to get at the final this tree :

[image]

Then you can get your *build-a-meal.swf* working fine.

Hope that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with swf is this swf required external swfs or other resources which must be loaded on the loading screen (first layer), and you must attach these external swfs or resources in place in order to have this swf works!